# No expected output for my performance testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance-testing

I want to do a performance test for my rails 3 app and I did a try according to the rails online guide

```
rake test:profile
```

and it gave some output as:

```
Specify ruby-prof as application's dependency in Gemfile to run benchmarks.
Loaded suite /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.326233 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

But according to the guide, there should be something like:

```
BrowsingTest#test_homepage (31 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 6 ms
              memory: 437.27 KB
             objects: 5,514
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 19 ms
```

and also some log files produced in app's tmp/performance dir, which doesn't exist in my case.

The performance test is the generated sample test, browsing_test.rb, in my app's test\performance dir:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  def test_homepage
    get '/'
  end
end
```

And my rails version is 3.0.10. Can anyone give me some tips or hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the exact same issue, and solved it by running

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --patch gcdata # Make sure you have the same patch version
```

(note: not sure how much that step helped since I had an error, but since it's part of what I did...)

Adding to my gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-prof', :git => 'git://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'
gem 'test-unit'
```

And of course running

```
bundle install
```

Some reading that helped me

- http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/08/14/performance-testing-rails-applications-how-to/
- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4171-fresh-rails-3-app-cannot-run-performance-tests
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#installing-gc-patched-mri

Comment: Hey, your solution works for my problem! Thank you very much! BTW, I didn't add that pacth, only installed the two gems, although I don't know why I have to install 'test-unit' to make 'ruby-prof' work correctly.

Comment: Glad I could help :). Now I have another problem with the benchmark helper methods mentioned in guides.rubyonrails.org. They don't output anything in my logs...